# Custom WordPress Theme - No Slider(s) Images

Tags: images

So I created a custom WordPress theme and the final thing what I need to add and create is a home page slider. But, whatever slider I'm installing, I cannot see images inside that slider. I've tried Master Slider, Huge IT Slider, and a few other ones and none of them showing images inside slider. It's showing navigation, title, links are working, descriptions - everything is working fine except that the slider doesn't show any images.

Then I inspect the slider itself (using Google Chrome Inspect Element extension) I see that it's loading the slider (I see a link to the image) but I cannot see it on the page.

Please, tell me if I need to add more information about my problem and if I need to upload my speicific code snippets to the question.

What could be the problem? Appreciate any help.

**EDIT:**
It looks like my theme doesn't support any of those slider plug-ins and I didn't know what to do in this kind of situation.

**EDIT 2:**

This is inside my functions.php file:

```
// Thumbnails support
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

I've also added these two lines, but it doesn't solve the problem:

```
add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'comment-list', 'comment-form', 'search-form', 'gallery', 'caption' ) );

add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'aside', 'gallery' ) );
```

This is how I'm getting content from the page inside my front-page.php file:

```
<?php
            $my_id = 8;
            $post_id_8 = get_post($my_id);
            $content = $post_id_8->post_content;
            $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
            $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
            echo $content;
 ?>
```

Comment: Support for 3rd Party Plugins are considered [Off-Topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. The same applies for plugin recommendations. Your best course of action is to try contacting the Plugin Author or visiting their support forums and raising an issue there. A simple solution could be just [adding theme support for thumbnails](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support).

Comment: Please provide some sample code.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I will delete this thread. But for the sake of the answer: I have already added `post_thumbails` support inside functions.php file. Same thing. Not showing any images.

Comment: I have added some code, but I don't think that this is the case (with front-page.php). I'm probably missing something inside my functions.php file.

Comment: I would note that this is a question not a discussion thread, these aren't forums. Keeping that in mind should explain a lot of the misunderstandings that happen on this site and help you get answers faster